# symfony2 what is the container aware

Tags: symfony

Im looking at writing my own console comands.  I noticed that it uses the container aware?  what is this?

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It provides you [access to the service container in your commands](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/console_command.html#getting-services-from-the-service-container) so you can fetch services from it.

Comment: im looking to run a report via a the console.  Its the same as the webbased report that I have setup but will send emails out.  Would I need to add a service for this?

Comment: You may want to access the mailer service to acually send the mail, so using container aware means you can do that easier.  $this->get('mailer')... etc

Comment: what about accessing other items from various bundles that I have created e.g. reports?

Comment: If you have configured those as services then sure, but it's more down to how you have structured the report generation. If you have the report generation as separate classes decoupled from their invocation in the frontend then it shouldn't be a problem. You could use the Twig render method to pass objects to your template, and have the result E-mailed, but that is far beyond what your question asked.